# Can't hold for loop result in an object in R

Tags: r

I have a vector call id as below:

```
id<-c("US_01_01", "US_01_02", "US_01_03", "UK_02_01", "UK_02_02", "UK_02_03", "CA_03_01", "CA_03_02", "CA_03_03")
```

I wish to save the output in a format as below into an object called obj:

```
US  01  01
US  01  02
US  01  03
UK  02  01
UK  02  02
UK  02  03
CA  03  01
CA  03  02
CA  03  03
```

The following is my code:

```
sp<-strsplit(id,"_")

sp<-as.array(sp)

obj<-vector("list",dim(sp))

for (i in 1:dim(sp)){
    obj[[i]] <- cat(sprintf("%s %s %s\n", sp[[i]][1], sp[[i]][2], sp[[i]][3]))
}
```

However, I don't know why the the output can't be saved into the object obj.

Thank you for help!

Comment: `cat` prints to the console, you can't save the output from `cat` into an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat` does not have a return value. Getting rid of it...

```
for (i in 1:dim(sp)){
    obj[[i]] <- sprintf("%s %s %s\n", sp[[i]][1], sp[[i]][2], sp[[i]][3])
}
```

Now we can attach the items together:

```
obj_full <- do.call(paste0,obj)
```

And you can `cat` that any time you want:

```
cat(obj_full)
# US 01 01
# US 01 02
# US 01 03
# UK 02 01
# UK 02 02
# UK 02 03
# CA 03 01
# CA 03 02
# CA 03 03
```

Of course, if you want to `cat` during the loop as well, you can just add another line for that.

---

**Finding documentation.** The "Value" section on the help page, `?cat`, explains that it returns nothing. This section is sometimes omitted, so it's also worth reviewing the "Description" section.

Comment: Might want to get rid of the new line "\n" inside the sprintf() command.

Comment: @untitled Why? It can be used as a separator when pasting instead, but without it, everything is on one line.

Comment: When I ran it, it did not seem to matter if it was there or not.

Comment: @untitled Okay. I'm not sure where the discrepancy is coming from, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Frank Thank you for the explanation. BTW, I noticed that using paste instead of paste0 would lead to the first line of the concatenated object misaligned with the following line. May I know why does this happen?

Comment: @Patrick `paste` by default separates entries with a space, so `"US 01 01\n"`, `" "`, `"US 01 02\n"`... and so on. This puts a leading space on all lines except the first.

Answer (score 2):

Try `read.table`

```
 read.table(text=id, sep='_', colClasses=rep('character',3))
 #  V1 V2 V3
 #1 US 01 01
 #2 US 01 02
 #3 US 01 03
 #4 UK 02 01
 #5 UK 02 02
 #6 UK 02 03
 #7 CA 03 01
 #8 CA 03 02
 #9 CA 03 03
```

Or

```
 library(splitstackshape)
 cSplit(as.data.frame(id), 'id', sep='_', type.convert=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
matrix(sapply(strsplit(id,"_"),paste,collapse=" "),ncol=1)

#output
      [,1]      
 [1,] "US 01 01"
 [2,] "US 01 02"
 [3,] "US 01 03"
 [4,] "UK 02 01"
 [5,] "UK 02 02"
 [6,] "UK 02 03"
 [7,] "CA 03 01"
 [8,] "CA 03 02"
 [9,] "CA 03 03"
```

Comment: Thanks to your idea, I have come up with another approach. 

cat(do.call(paste0,lapply(1:9, function(i) sprintf("%s %s %s\n", sp[[i]][1], sp[[i]][2], sp[[i]][3]))))

The sp above are sp before being converted to array